# What's the difference between myObject.MyField and myObject.MyField() in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I stumbled upon this issue:

`myObject`'s class has a public field `MyField` which type is `Decimal?`

I accidentally access the field as if it were a property with this code:

```
myObject.MyField()
```

instead of

```
myObject.MyField
```

And I got the following error from the compiler: `Structure 'Decimal?' cannot be indexed because it has no default property`

Documentation [on this error on MSND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fst9zcwd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is very short and I just don't understand what it means.

**Q: What's the meaning of `myObject.MyField()` if it has one, and why can't I use it on my field if so?**

Note: my problem is now solved but I would like to understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access elements of an array using `()` in VB.NET.  The error message is telling you `Structure 'Decimal?' cannot be indexed` because it can't.

Comment: There was nothing between the parenthesis... but you might be right

Answer (score 1):

In that context it is the index operator, just like `[]` in C#.

To be more precise, in VB.NET it is called "default property" and in C# it is called "indexer".

See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/manoj/archive/2004/10/15/15891.aspx) for even more details.